# Batch command vcvarsall.bat errors with "input line is too long" on Azure DevOps server

Tags: windows, batch-file, azure-devops

I am running a batch file on Azure DevOps server pipeline as batch script task.
This batch file internally invokes Intel Parallel studio compiler 2019 update 3 like this:

```
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    call "%ICPP_COMPILER19%bin\compilervars.bat" intel64 vs2017
)
```

and later calls build file.

Lately, I am observing this command throws error as:

```
##[command]C:\build_dir\test.bat

Intel(R) MPI Library 2019 Update 3 for Windows* Target Build Environment for Intel(R) 64 applications
Copyright 2007-2019 Intel Corporation.

Copyright (C) 1985-2019 Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.
Intel(R) Compiler 19.0 Update 3 (package 203)
 
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.0.26228.57
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'
The input line is too long.
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

What is this error and why now? I saw many questions related to this but I couldn't find answers related to my query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`The input line is too long.` normally happens after a percent expansion with a resulting line longer than 8191 characters.

In your case it's probably a path/includedir variable overflowing after appending something.
The cause for such problems could be a recursion or multiple invocation of the batch file.
Then you should see that the same path was appended multiple times.

Another problem could be that your project paths are very long, like
`C:\my insane Projects\are nested\into a structure\that is much too deep\...<2000 characters later>\myProject`

Check your `PATH` variable, sometimes it's ridiculous long with many repetitions.

To find your problem, add some `echo #123` into `compilervars.bat` to find the exact line.
Then analyse the problematic variable.

Comment: First of all apologies for replying late. Thanks for the pointer. I did check my PATH and it was overloaded with same Intel2019 installation  path, since I am calling this batch script three times (debug, release, research). After your suggestion and some more research, I setup only once the call to invoke Intel2019 compiler (call "%ICPP_COMPILER19%bin\compilervars.bat" intel64 vs2017) in TFS pipeline. So now everytime the batch script is called it wont try to invoke the compiler again as the env is already set for it.

Answer (score 0):

My fix was involved resetting the path variable since it got overloaded due to an error in my build script that would run every time I built my project.

Running an `echo %PATH%` helped me see how long my path variable was.